# Check play state of AVPlayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avfoundation, avplayer

Is there a way to know whether an `AVPlayer` playback has stalled or reached the end?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

To get notification for reaching the end of an item (via [Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH3-SW7)):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
      addObserver:<self>
      selector:@selector(<#The selector name#>)
      name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification 
      object:<#A player item#>];
```

And to track playing you can:

"track changes in the position of the playhead in an AVPlayer object" by using **addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:queue:usingBlock:** or **addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes:queue:usingBlock:**.

Example is from Apple:

```
// Assume a property: @property (retain) id playerObserver;

Float64 durationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds([<#An asset#> duration]);
CMTime firstThird = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(durationSeconds/3.0, 1);
CMTime secondThird = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(durationSeconds*2.0/3.0, 1);
NSArray *times = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSValue valueWithCMTime:firstThird], [NSValue valueWithCMTime:secondThird], nil];

self.playerObserver = [<#A player#> addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes:times queue:NULL usingBlock:^{
    // Passing NULL for the queue specifies the main queue.

    NSString *timeDescription = (NSString *)CMTimeCopyDescription(NULL, [self.player currentTime]);
    NSLog(@"Passed a boundary at %@", timeDescription);
    [timeDescription release];
}];
```

Comment: You could throw in a Boolean flag to check the play status.

Comment: Notifications might cause problems if you change player's item, for example, with `-replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:`, and don't handle it properly. A more reliable way for me is to track `AVPlayer`'s status using KVO. See my answer below for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34321993/3160561

Comment: Also need notification of error?  `AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTimeNotification`

Answer (score 361):

You can tell it's playing using:

```
AVPlayer *player = ...
if ((player.rate != 0) && (player.error == nil)) {
    // player is playing
}
```

Swift 3 extension:

```
extension AVPlayer {
    var isPlaying: Bool {
        return rate != 0 && error == nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Not necessarily, it doesn't handle situations where the player stalls due an error in the file. Something I found out the hard way...

Comment: As Dermot said, if you try to play something while in airplane mode, the AVPlayer rate is still set to 1.0, since it implies the intention to play.

Comment: Is there a better solution?

Comment: The AVPlayer has an error property, just check that it isn't nil as well as checking the rate isn't 0 :)

Comment: Note that the answer has been updated to prevent @Dermot scenario. So this one actually works.

Comment: Will not be working when playing video footage reverse (`- [AVPlayer setRate:-1.0]`), because `-1.0` is less than 0.

Comment: note that when using the above example with Swift, `player.error` is an optional not a bool, and so for this to compile, you'll need to change it to `player.rate > 0 && (player.error == nil)`

Comment: This answer does NOT distinguish between "stalled" and "ended"!  I think combine this answer with maxkonovalov's answer. And note Julian's comment, the test should be `player.rate != 0`, so that playing in reverse isn't considered stopped.

Comment: This will also not work after `player.replaceCurrentItem(with: nil)` when player is actually not playing, but `player.rate` will still be != 0

Comment: I had the player stuck at rat 1.0 although I was not in airplane mode. So there some other condition that need to be included in the test.

Comment: Very useful addition to my `Macros.m`, thank you. `#define isAVPlayerPlaying(player) ((player.rate != 0) && (player.error == nil))`

Answer (score 78):

In iOS10, there's a built in property for this now: *timeControlStatus*

For example, this function plays or pauses the avPlayer based on it's status and updates the play/pause button appropriately.

```
@IBAction func btnPlayPauseTap(_ sender: Any) {
    if aPlayer.timeControlStatus == .playing {
        aPlayer.pause()
        btnPlay.setImage(UIImage(named: "control-play"), for: .normal)
    } else if aPlayer.timeControlStatus == .paused {
        aPlayer.play()
        btnPlay.setImage(UIImage(named: "control-pause"), for: .normal)
    }
}
```

As for your second question, to know if the avPlayer reached the end, the easiest thing to do would be to set up a notification.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.didPlayToEnd), name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil)
```

When it gets to the end, for example, you can have it rewind to the beginning of the video and reset the Pause button to Play.

```
@objc func didPlayToEnd() {
    aPlayer.seek(to: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0, 1))
    btnPlay.setImage(UIImage(named: "control-play"), for: .normal)
}
```

These examples are useful if you're creating your own controls, but if you use a AVPlayerViewController, then the controls come built in.

Comment: Easy to use for iOS 10+

Comment: @objc func didPlayToEnd() for Swift 4.2

Answer (score 25):

`rate` is **NOT** the way to check whether a video is *playing* (it could stalled). From documentation of `rate`:

> Indicates the desired rate of playback; 0.0 means "paused", 1.0 indicates a desire to play at the natural rate of the current item.

Key words "desire to play" - **a rate of `1.0` does not mean the video is playing.**

The solution since iOS 10.0 is to use `AVPlayerTimeControlStatus` which can be observed on `AVPlayer` `timeControlStatus` property.

The solution prior to iOS 10.0 (9.0, 8.0 etc.) is to roll your own solution. **A rate of `0.0` means that the video is paused. When `rate != 0.0` it means that the video is either playing *or* is stalled.**

You can find out the difference by observing player time via: `func addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval interval: CMTime, queue: DispatchQueue?, using block: @escaping (CMTime) -> Void) -> Any`

The block returns the current player time in `CMTime`, so a comparison of `lastTime` (the time that was last received from the block) and `currentTime` (the time that the block just reported) will tell whether the player is playing or is stalled. For example, if `lastTime == currentTime` and `rate != 0.0`, then the player has stalled.

As noted by others, figuring out whether playback has finished is indicated by `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification`.

Answer (score 18):

For **Swift**:

*AVPlayer*:

```
let player = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.sample.com/movie.mov"))
if (player.rate != 0 && player.error == nil) {
   println("playing")
}
```

**Update**:
`player.rate > 0` condition changed to `player.rate != 0` because if video  is playing in reverse it can be negative thanks to *Julian* for pointing out. 
**Note**: This might look same as above(Maz's) answer but in Swift '!player.error' was giving me a compiler error so you have to check for error using 'player.error == nil' in Swift.(because error property is not of 'Bool' type)

*AVAudioPlayer:*

```
if let theAudioPlayer =  appDelegate.audioPlayer {
   if (theAudioPlayer.playing) {
       // playing
   }
}
```

*AVQueuePlayer:*

```
if let theAudioQueuePlayer =  appDelegate.audioPlayerQueue {
   if (theAudioQueuePlayer.rate != 0 && theAudioQueuePlayer.error == nil) {
       // playing
   }
}
```

Comment: AVPlayer != AVAudioPlayer

Comment: Caveats: all mentioned above in the answer that showed up two years before this one.

Comment: @Yar I know also upvoted above answer but this is for swift and in Swift '!player.error' was not working for me it is allowed only for bool types so I have added the answer oops upvoted your comment by mistake to give reply using this stack overflow app :)

Comment: My concern is that I don't know how well the player.error not being nil actually works.

Comment: Will not be working when playing video footage reverse (`player.rate = -1.0`), because -1.0 is less than 0.

Answer (score 18):

A more reliable alternative to `NSNotification` is to add yourself as observer to player's `rate` property.

```
[self.player addObserver:self
              forKeyPath:@"rate"
                 options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                 context:NULL];
```

Then check if the new value for observed rate is zero, which means that playback has stopped for some reason, like reaching the end or stalling because of empty buffer.

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)change
                       context:(void *)context {
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"rate"]) {
        float rate = [change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] floatValue];
        if (rate == 0.0) {
            // Playback stopped
        } else if (rate == 1.0) {
            // Normal playback
        } else if (rate == -1.0) {
            // Reverse playback
        }
    }
}
```

For `rate == 0.0` case, to know what exactly caused the playback to stop, you can do the following checks:

```
if (self.player.error != nil) {
    // Playback failed
}
if (CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player.currentTime) >=
    CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player.currentItem.duration)) {
    // Playback reached end
} else if (!self.player.currentItem.playbackLikelyToKeepUp) {
    // Not ready to play, wait until enough data is loaded
}
```

And don't forget to make your player stop when it reaches the end:

`self.player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndPause;`

Comment: I think also need notification of failure to reach end - `AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTimeNotification`. If this error happens, will never reach the end time.  Or reading maz's answer, add to your code a check for `player.error != nil`, in which case playback has "ended" due to error.

Comment: BTW, what did you find "not reliable" about using NSNotification of `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification`?

Comment: ToolmakerSteve, thanks for your note, added error check to my answer.
For not reliable notifications - I came across the issue myself while implementing repeating and reusable player views in collection view, and KVO made things more clear, as it allowed to keep it all more local without different players' notifications interfering with each other.

Answer (score 16):

Currently with swift 5 the easiest way to check if the player is playing or paused is to check the *.timeControlStatus* variable.

```
player.timeControlStatus == .paused
player.timeControlStatus == .playing
```

Comment: This is not the right way to do this. The question wants to know when the player has reached the end. The user pausing playback will also activate this function, which will lead to unintended effects.

Answer (score 10):

Swift extension based on the answer by maz

```
extension AVPlayer {

    var isPlaying: Bool {
        return ((rate != 0) && (error == nil))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

> **Answer in Objective C**

```
if (player.timeControlStatus == AVPlayerTimeControlStatusPlaying) {
    //player is playing
}
else if (player.timeControlStatus == AVPlayerTimeControlStatusPaused) {
    //player is pause
}
else if (player.timeControlStatus == AVPlayerTimeControlStatusWaitingToPlayAtSpecifiedRate) {
    //player is waiting to play
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The Swift version of maxkonovalov's answer is this:

```
player.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "rate", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)
```

and

```
override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    if keyPath == "rate" {
        if let rate = change?[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] as? Float {
            if rate == 0.0 {
                print("playback stopped")
            }
            if rate == 1.0 {
                print("normal playback")
            }
            if rate == -1.0 {
                print("reverse playback")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you maxkonovalov!

Comment: Hello Mr Stanev, thanks for your answer. This doesn't work for me (aka doesn't print anything in the console?)

Comment: Nevermind, it does work – my player was `nil`! But I need to know when the view starts (not ends). Any way to do that?

Answer (score 5):

```
player.timeControlStatus == AVPlayer.TimeControlStatus.playing
```

Comment: This provided answer may be correct, but **it could benefit from an explanation**. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the player is playing with a timer like this :

```
let playerObserver = self.player.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, preferredTimescale: 1), queue: DispatchQueue.main, using: { [weak self] time in
        if self?.player.timeControlStatus == .playing {
            debugPrint("#player - info: isPlaying")
            self?.playButton.isSelected = true
        } else if self?.player.timeControlStatus == .paused {
            debugPrint("#player - info: isPaused")
            self?.playButton.isSelected = false
        } else if self?.player.timeControlStatus == .waitingToPlayAtSpecifiedRate {
            debugPrint("#player - info: isWaiting") //Buffering
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `AsyncStream` version of the solution

```
extension AVPlayer {
    func isPlaying() -> AsyncStream<Bool> {
        AsyncStream { cont in
            let observation = self.observe(\.rate) { player, value in
                cont.yield(player.timeControlStatus == .playing)
            }
            cont.yield(timeControlStatus == .playing)
            cont.onTermination = { _ in
                observation.invalidate()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it

```
let stream = player.isPlaying()
for await isPlaying in stream {
    self.isPlaying = isPlaying
}
```

And in SwiftUI you can use it inside `.task`.

```
.task {
    let stream = player.isPlaying()
    for await isPlaying in stream {
        self.isPlaying = isPlaying
    }
}
```