# AVPlayer, notification for play/pause state?

Tags: ios, avplayer

I'm searching for a way to get notified the exact moment when `AVPlayer` starts playing. There's the "rate" property, but currently I am checking it periodically with an `NSTimer` to get updates.

I tried KVO, but apparently it's not KVO compliant.

I know that there are [events](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html) when the player [ENDED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655864/check-play-state-of-avplayer). But i'm talking about pause here.

I also KVO subscribed to `AVPlayerItem's` "status", but it's showing me when the HTTP asset has finished caching, no play/pause. I also started collecting all calls of play/pause, requesting an instant UI update afterwards, but it takes some more runloops before `AVPlayer` really starts playing. I'd just love to update my button *instantly*.

Comment: There is a way to monitor whether the AVPlayer is playing listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9288642/2383604

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For i**OS 10** onwards You can check new property of AVPlayer **timeControlStatus**.

```
if(avPlayerObject.timeControlStatus==AVPlayerTimeControlStatusPaused)
{
//Paused mode
}
else if(avPlayerObject.timeControlStatus==AVPlayerTimeControlStatusPlaying)
{
 //Play mode
}
```

Comment: but how do you actually get notified when it changes?

Answer (score 51):

Why do you say that "rate" is not KVO complaint?
It works for me.

Here is what I did:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ...

    [self.player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"rate" options:0 context:nil];
}
```

And then:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"rate"]) {
    if ([self.player rate]) {
        [self changeToPause];  // This changes the button to Pause
    }
    else {
        [self changeToPlay];   // This changes the button to Play
    }
}
}
```

Comment: really? did you try that on iOS4 or iOS5? Will re-do my tests; maybe it was just my mistake after all.

Comment: I tried it in iOS5. In order to my observer get called, I had to add the observer with options: `NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew`.

Comment: Is there any alternative for iOS 10?

Comment: @AymenHARRATH Check my answer for iOS 10.

Comment: Is there a way to differentiate who was the person pausing it? Like did the user pause it, or did we pause it programmatically, or was it due to error?

Answer (score 6):

AVPalyer as default observer to track the current duration of the video ,when you pause or resume the video you can get paused time by using one global variable (inside observer update that variable)

```
CMTime interval = CMTimeMake(1, 1);

//The capture of self here is coming in with your implicit property access of self.currentduration - you can't refer to self or properties on self from within a block that will be strongly retained by self.

//You can get around this by creating a weak reference to self before accessing timerDisp inside your block
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

self.timeObserverToken = [_player addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:interval queue:NULL usingBlock: ^(CMTime time)
{
    _currentDuration = (int)CMTimeGetSeconds (_player.currentTime);

    if(!_isPlaying)
    {
        _pausedDuration = _currentDuration;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're targeting iOS 13 and up, you can pull this off elegantly using `Combine`:

```swift
cancellable = myAVPlayerInstance.publisher(for: \.timeControlStatus)
    .sink { [unowned self] status in
       ...
    }
```

where `status` is any `case` of `AVPlayer.TimeControlStatus`

Answer (score 3):

```
player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
player.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "rate", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new, context: nil)

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
  if keyPath == "rate" {
    if player.rate > 0 {
      print("video started")
    }
  }
}
```

in swift

Answer (score 1):

Add an observer to your `AVPlayer` object's `rate` value:

```
player.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "rate", options: [], context: nil)
```

And override the method that will be called when the `rate` changes:

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if keyPath == "rate", let player = object as? AVPlayer {
        if player.rate == 1 {
            print("Playing")
        } else {
            print("Paused")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is buggy, what if the player is set on a rate other than 1 (e.g. 0.5)?

Answer (score 0):

Need to add an observer to `AVPlayer` object's `rate` value:

```
player?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "rate", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new, context: nil)
```

Override below method to observe changes in  `rate` property

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if keyPath == "rate" {
        if let status = player?.timeControlStatus {
            switch status{
            case .paused:
                //Paused mode
                print("paused")
            case .waitingToPlayAtSpecifiedRate:
                //Resumed
                print("resumed")
            case .playing:
                //Video Ended
                print("ended")
            @unknown default:
                print("For future versions")
            }
        }
    }
}
```