# Detect when AvPlayer is stopped

Tags: ios, avplayer

I'm using the AVPlayer class to read streams.
I have to monitor playback.

Here is my question : Is it possible to detect when the player is stopped by the user ?

I looked at MPMoviePlayerController. If the user stopped the video, this controller sends a notification : MPMovieFinishReasonUserExited. Is there an equivalent ?

Comment: [refer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837002/no-avplayer-delegate-how-to-track-when-song-finished-playing-objective-c-iphon) . Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried but the notification "AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification" is never by the player.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect when AVPlayer video ends playing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29386531/how-to-detect-when-avplayer-video-ends-playing)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here's the swift 3 code for @Thlbaut's answer

```
self.avPlayer?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "rate", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions(rawValue: 0), context: nil)
```

then

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if keyPath == "rate" {
        if let playRate = self.avPlayer?.rate {
            if playRate == 0.0 {
                print("playback paused")
            } else {
                print("playback started")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can monitor `rate` property by adding observer on the player for key `rate`.

> A value of `0.0` means pauses the video, while a value of `1.0` play at the natural rate of the current item.

[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVPlayer/rate) and [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7701427/2679170).

Hope this helps.