# AVPlayer playing even though rate property is 0

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayeritem

[This other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655864/check-play-state-of-avplayer) suggests when the `rate` property for an `AVPlayer` is 0, it means the `AVPlayer` is no longer playing. We use the observer code below to loop a video, but sometimes invoking the `pause` function on the player fails to break the looping. When debugging, the `rate` property evaluates to 0.

1) Is the linked SO post wrong, in that a rate value of 0 does not mean the player is paused?

2) Is the continuous looping, even after the `pause` function is invoked, some kind of race condition where the `pause` function comes after the `playerItemDidReachEnd` notification is already issued?

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "playerItemDidReachEnd:", name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: playerItem)

private func playVideo() {
    player.seekToTime(kCMTimeZero)
    player.actionAtItemEnd = .Pause
    player.play()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when setting up the player:

```
player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEnd.None

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, 
                                                 selector: "playerItemDidReachEnd:", 
                                                 name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, 
                                                 object: player.currentItem)
```

this will prevent the player to pause at the end.

in the notification:

```
func playerItemDidReachEnd(notification: NSNotification) {
    let p: AVPlayerItem = notification.object as! AVPlayerItem
    p.seekToTime(kCMTimeZero)
}
```

this will rewind the movie.

Don't forget to unregister the notification when releasing the player.