# How to pass an AVPlayer from Source VC to Destination VC using a custom segue?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, uistoryboardsegue

I created a simple `ViewController` class that plays a livestream video using `AVPlayer`. The livestream is loaded in `viewDidLoad` and when the user presses play, it plays the livestream, simple enough.

The parent VC is set for portrait orientation only.

I have another button that segues to another `ViewController` using a custom segue.

How do I pass the AVPlayer and its "state" to the destination `ViewController`?......i.e. if the AVPlayer is currently playing, it should maintain its state when it's passed from parent VC to destination VC.

FYI: I'm not using `prepareForSegue`.

Here's the complete simple code:

**ViewController.swift:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var playerView: UIView!
    var player = AVPlayer()
    var avPlayerLayer: AVPlayerLayer!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = "http://vevoplaylist-live.hls.adaptive.level3.net/vevo/ch1/appleman.m3u8"  //"http://68.235.37.11:1935/vietmagazine/vietmagazine/playlist.m3u8"

        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem( URL:NSURL( string:url )! )
        player = AVPlayer(playerItem:playerItem)

        avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)

        // Add the layer to the view
        playerView.layer.insertSublayer(avPlayerLayer, atIndex: 0)

    }

    @IBAction func playVIdeo(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        avPlayerLayer.player!.play()
    }

    @IBAction func change(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        avPlayerLayer.player!.pause()

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("CustomSegue", sender: self)
    }

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

        // Layout subviews manually
        avPlayerLayer.frame = playerView.bounds   
    }
}
```

**CustomSegue.swift:**

```
class CustomSegue: UIStoryboardSegue
{
    override func perform()
    {
        let sourceVC = self.sourceViewController
        let destinationVC = self.destinationViewController

        sourceVC.view.addSubview(destinationVC.view)

        destinationVC.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.05, 0.05)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: { () -> Void in

            destinationVC.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0)

            } ) { (finished) -> Void in

                destinationVC.view.removeFromSuperview()

                let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(0.001 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))

                dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

                    sourceVC.presentViewController(destinationVC, animated: false, completion: nil)

                })
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you figured it out?

Answer (score 0):

Would passing the `AVPlayer` instance be enough to pass the player and its state?

Not tested, but does this work? In the first view controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  var player = AVPlayer()

  @IBAction func myAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("TheSegue", sender: self)
  }
}

class MySegue: UIStoryboardSegue {
  override func perform() {
      let viewController = sourceViewController as! ViewController
      let secondViewController = destinationViewController as! SecondViewController
      secondViewController.player = viewController.player
      sourceViewController.presentViewController(destinationViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

And in the second view controller:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    var player: AVPlayer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // Do something with the player
    }
}
```

Note, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9288642/1305067) show how to check an `AVPlayer`;'s state.