# Play audio and vibration simultaneously on ios using swift

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, audiotoolbox

Is there any way to play audio file and vibrate iphone when audio is started and stop vibrating when audio stops playing?

currently this code is working but it plays audio and when audio stops then it vibrates the phone, I want both (audio and vibration) play together.

```
var alertSoundEffect: AVAudioPlayer?

let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "alert.mp3", ofType:nil)!
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

do {
    alertSoundEffect = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
    alertSoundEffect?.prepareToPlay()
    alertSoundEffect?.play()
} catch {
    return
}

let vib = SystemSoundID(1519)
AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(vib))
AudioServicesRemoveSystemSoundCompletion(vib)
```

Comment: see this it helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655864/check-play-state-of-avplayer/9288642

Comment: Its helpful thanks, but main problem is to stop vibration at the stage when audio ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
 DispatchQueue.global().async 
 {
      var alertSoundEffect: AVAudioPlayer?

      let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "alert.mp3", ofType:nil)!
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

        do {
            alertSoundEffect = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            alertSoundEffect?.prepareToPlay()
            alertSoundEffect?.play()
        } catch {
            return
        }

 }
```

Comment: but still a little problem, can I stop vibration manually or any way when audio stops then vibration should also stop?

Comment: I don't think you can stop the vibration manually it plays by the system , you may synchronize the time of mp3 with it

Comment: ok one last thing .. Can we change duration of vibration .. I want to vibrate for very short time say 0.1 second

Comment: for sorry also you can't but 1519 and 1520 are the lowest ones